# Request filtering does not work properly in IIS 10

Tags: iis-10

To prevent path traversal attack, I add some settings in request filtering (in Rule and URL tabs) but they does not work properly.
For example I add ".." in "Deny String" and in "Deny Sequence" but IIS accept it (e.g. ../../css/test.txt).
Also I add "*/../*.*" in "Block Request Rule" in URL rewrite, but it does not work too.

Is there anything wrong in my settings?

Comment: Probably there won't be more comments than https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1155844/request-filtering-does-not-work-properly-in-iis-10.html

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make a tests with the Request Filtering rules by adding `..`. While testing I set the Failed Request Tracing rule to check what is happening in the background. I noticed that while we try to browse the path by adding `..` in the URL, it converts it to the normal URL. i.e. `localhost/../../css/test.txt` becomes `localhost/css/test.txt`.

**See below test result**

[image]

[image]

If you are looking for a URL Rewrite rule to block the path (folder/files) acesss then below rule is working on my side.

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="*" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/test_folder/*" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

You could modify the rule as per your requirements.